# SQL Searching and Order case of where clause

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, sql-like

I have simple a search function

```
SELECT bar FROM `foo` 
WHERE (bar like '%search1%') || (bar like '%search2%') ... (maybe more)
```

I want to order result by which one is most acurate answer.

If my table like this

```
1 : sometext search1 sometext
2 : sometext search2 sometext
3 : search1 search2 sometext
```

i want to bring 3rd row to top of results (cause its contain both of search1 and search2)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the `order by`.  Here is a general method:

```
SELECT bar
FROM `foo` 
ORDER BY ((case when bar like '%search1%' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when bar like '%search2%' then 1 else 0 end) +
          . . .
         ) desc;
```